# What is an elegant way to slice a pandas dataframe by a condition AND a date range at the same time?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, indexing, numpy-slicing

So I am searching for a simple solution for changing the content of a dataframe based on both a condition and a time range. See code below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(15,2), index = pd.DatetimeIndex(start = "2018-01-01 00:00", end = "2018-01-01 00:14", freq="1min"), columns = ["A", "B"])


data.loc[data["A"].between(0.2,0.3), :].loc[:"2018-01-01 00:02", "A"] = 4

# /Users/ap/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:189: SettingWithCopyWarning:
# A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

# See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
#   self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
# __main__:1: SettingWithCopyWarning:
# A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

# See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

print(data)

#                             A         B
# 2018-01-01 00:00:00  0.146793  0.198634
# 2018-01-01 00:01:00  0.284354  0.422438
# 2018-01-01 00:02:00  0.359768  0.199127
# 2018-01-01 00:03:00  0.306145  0.538669
# 2018-01-01 00:04:00  0.839377  0.299983
# 2018-01-01 00:05:00  0.236554  0.127450
# 2018-01-01 00:06:00  0.262167  0.304692
# 2018-01-01 00:07:00  0.341273  0.099983
# 2018-01-01 00:08:00  0.721702  0.763717
# 2018-01-01 00:09:00  0.196948  0.541878
# 2018-01-01 00:10:00  0.673248  0.421809
# 2018-01-01 00:11:00  0.892244  0.070801
# 2018-01-01 00:12:00  0.354958  0.184147
# 2018-01-01 00:13:00  0.062060  0.840900
# 2018-01-01 00:14:00  0.139046  0.742875

# ==> Nothing happened as indicated by the warning


# non-elegant way to solve the issue:
x = data.loc[data["A"].between(0.2,0.3), :]
x.loc[:"2018-01-01 00:02", "A"] = 4
data.loc[x.index,:] = x

print(data)

#                             A         B
# 2018-01-01 00:00:00  0.146793  0.198634
# 2018-01-01 00:01:00  4.000000  0.422438
# 2018-01-01 00:02:00  0.359768  0.199127
# 2018-01-01 00:03:00  0.306145  0.538669
# 2018-01-01 00:04:00  0.839377  0.299983
# 2018-01-01 00:05:00  0.236554  0.127450
# 2018-01-01 00:06:00  0.262167  0.304692
# 2018-01-01 00:07:00  0.341273  0.099983
# 2018-01-01 00:08:00  0.721702  0.763717
# 2018-01-01 00:09:00  0.196948  0.541878
# 2018-01-01 00:10:00  0.673248  0.421809
# 2018-01-01 00:11:00  0.892244  0.070801
# 2018-01-01 00:12:00  0.354958  0.184147
# 2018-01-01 00:13:00  0.062060  0.840900
# 2018-01-01 00:14:00  0.139046  0.742875
```

Also I do know that I can make two conditions out of it like this, but I do not consider this as an "elegant" solution cause I do not make use of the nice time span functionality of pandas anymore:

```
from datetime import datetime
data.loc[(data["A"].between(0.2,0.3)) & (data.index < datetime.strptime("2018-01-01 00:02", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")), "A"] = 4
```

Comment: This edit is less than 6 characters, but the data generation should read: `data = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.rand(15,2), index = pd.DatetimeIndex(start = "2018-01-01 00:00", end = "2018-01-01 00:14", freq="1min"), columns = ["A", "B"])`. A bracket has changed position.

Comment: I edited it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
data.loc[:"2018-01-01 00:02","A"][data.loc[:"2018-01-01 00:02", "A"].between(0.2,0.3)]=4
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but my personal opinion is that the solution stated at the end of my question is superior to this one. I consider the use of "list()" more as a workaround than my use of two conditions to be honest.

Comment: Most probably I did not understand what you ask in the question. My understanding was that you want to be able to use `loc[:"2018-01-01 00:02","A"]` and that's what I did. Maybe you could clarify the question.

Comment: I was looking for a elegant version and I was not 100% happy with my last suggestions because I did not use the time span syntax in there. That is true, if that is what you understood. But the whole purpose of the question is to figure out whether there is a better way without using little hacks like the "list()" syntax. As no one else replied yet, I guess that there is none. :(

Comment: In fact, you can drop the list() - as in the new edit of the answer

Comment: Ah, cool! Now I do like your solution better than mine and it might be the best answer on my question. Thanks!